# objects added to array but count is zero

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Below is a method for handling creation of balls depending on colour and some other properties. The createBall method returns a CCPhysicsSprite. numberOfBallsToCreate returns one of each colour but five for black.

```
-(void)ballCreation:(b2World*)world inLayer:(CCLayer*)layer   {

CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
ballType = blackBall;

for (int i = 0; i < [self numberOfBallsToCreate]; i++) {


switch (ballType) {
    case greenBall: 
        [self createBall:world inLayer:layer atPosition:[self ballPosition] ballImage:@"greenBall.png"];

        break;

    case redBall: 
        [self createBall:world inLayer:layer atPosition:[self ballPosition] ballImage:@"redBall.png"];

        break;

    case blueBall:  
        [self createBall:world inLayer:layer atPosition:[self ballPosition] ballImage:@"blueBall.png"];

        break;

    case blackBall:   
        [blackBallArray addObject:[self createBall:world inLayer:layer atPosition:[self ballBirdPositions] ballImage:@"blackBall.png"] ];

      break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

}

Also below is a method that I update every 1/60 of a second, applying force on each ball. All the ball updates are working well except the blackBall.

```
-(void)updateBalls   {

switch ([self getBallType]) {
    case greenBall:
        [self applyGreenForce];
        break;

    case redBall:
        [self applyRedForce];
        break;

    case blueBall:
        [self applyBlueForce];
        break;

    case blackBall:    {
        //[self applyBlackForce];
        createdBlackBallArray = [self getBlackBallArray];
        CCLOG(@"the createdBlackBallArray count is %d", createdBlackBallArray.count); // always prints zero
        if (createdBlackBallArray != NULL) {
            //CCLOG(@"code reached here");
            for (int i = 0; i < createdBlackBallArray.count; i++) {
                CCPhysicsSprite* blackBallPhysicsSprite = [createdBlackBallArray objectAtIndex:i];
                //if (blackBallPhysicsSprite.b2Body != NULL) {
                b2Vec2 ballForce = b2Vec2(1.0, 0.5);
                blackBallPhysicsSprite.b2Body->ApplyForce(ballForce, blackBallPhysicsSprite.b2Body->GetWorldCenter() );

            }

            }
        }

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

The CCLOG above always gives zero for the array count so the force will not be applied. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The getBlackBallArray details are below:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getblackBallArray   {

return blackBallArray;
}
```

How can I solve this?

**UPDATED**

Here is the initWithBall method where the arrays are initialized.

```
-(id)initWithBall:(b2World*)world inLayer:(CCLayer*)layer {

[self ballCreation:world inLayer:layer];

blackBallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
createdBlackBallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
return self;
}
```

Part of the Ball.h class is below:

```
#import "GameObjects.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ballTypes) {
blueBall = 0, 
blackBall = 1, 
redBall = 2,  
greenBall = 3,  


};

@interface Ball : CCNode    {

b2Body* ballBody;
b2World* ballWorld;
CCLayer* ballLayer;
ballTypes ballType;
NSString* ballImageName;
NSMutableArray* blackBallArray;
NSMutableArray* createdBlackBallArray;

}

-(void)updateBalls;
@end
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from this code sample, but that's symptomatic of failing to initialize `blackBallArray` before trying to add objects to it.

Comment: @Rob: I initialized the `blackBallArray`  and also the `createdBlackBallArray`  in the init method.

Comment: I'd put a log statement where you're inserting the ball confirming the contents of the array before and after adding the object. This confirms (a) you got to the line that does the inserting; and (b) that the array you're inserting to is not `nil`.

Comment: To Rob's point we also don't see where you init createdBlackBallArray. Since you're attempting to dump the contents of blackBallArray to this new array it would be nice to see how they're instantiated.

Comment: A note about coding standards: you should not compare Objective-C objects to `NULL`, you should [compare them to `nil`](http://nshipster.com/nil/) instead.

Comment: @Rob: the array count before and after adding an object is also zero

Comment: @D80Buckeye: I just updated the code

Comment: @user2456145 You show us the declaration of `initWithBall`, but not your invocation of that. I'd suggest you put a `NSLog` in there and make sure you're hitting that method (and not, for example, just calling `init`).

Comment: @Rob: `initWithBall` is okay because the other balls are working. I only create one of them at a time so I don't need an array for them.

Comment: @user2456145 Fine, if the "`count`" before and after "adding" an object is zero, that suggests that `blackBallArray` must be `nil` (log it and see) and thus, your attempt to `addObject` would therefore do nothing. If this is indeed the case, it means that your `initWithBall` (or whatever you're doing to initialize that array) is not getting called. Without the code we're just guessing, but I'd wager that array is not getting initialized like you think it is (or it's getting re-set to `nil` at some point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made a small mistake in your code. You have initialized blackBallArray after calling ballCreation method.

It should be like this:

```
-(id)initWithBall:(b2World*)world inLayer:(CCLayer*)layer {
if ((self = [super init]) != nil)
{

//Initialize array first
  blackBallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  createdBlackBallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  [self ballCreation:world inLayer:layer];
}
  return self;
}
```

A word of caution. When putting up a post always make sure only most important code is added. You really put up a lot of code which made it a bit confusing to go through. Happy coding.